# How can I add a background to a logo?

Tags: backgrounds

Is there a way of making the white areas in a picture transparent, so that when placed on a background, the background colour appears on the picture where there was previously white?

In fact I’m trying to insert a logo on a blue background. I just want the logo to appear on top of the background, but when I insert it on the background, a white rectangular box appears around the logo, because the white parts in picture file containing the logo aren’t transparent. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: This is no question releated to TeX I think. It's a problem of your used image. Ask your institution for an logo with an transparent background and (if allowed, it depends on the CI of the institution) the foreground in white.

Comment: So you want to *remove* the white background and not add a background like you title suggests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see your image is in JPG format.  AFAIK, JPG does not support transparency.  So what I did was (1) opened the image in gimp; (2) added alpha-channel (this is transparency in image-speak); (3) saved it as a PNG image (`dmcmn.png`).

Then I compiled a simple file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{blue!20}
\includegraphics{dmcmn}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your help, that's exactly what I was looking for.